# Images not rendering

Tags: html, css, image

Why are two of my images not rendering? It works when I use notepad++, but not when I upload it to my FTP.

Comment: Inspect the page and you will easily figure out that the image cannot be found. Either because it's not on the server; or it has a different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

403, forbidden message is there for this error

```
http://example.com/em_w/02/37/98/837-02379877w.jpg
```

This is the photo which can't be opened by the browser. The link that is given is not accessible through the server. If you go to this link, you will see the photo.

HINT: hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, which will open up Firebug. Switch to console view, and reload the page. From there, you can see if something's wrong.y